# When I press certain keys together it triggers other keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, a problem I'm having is when I press the letters <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd>, on google chrome it goes up to the search bar and highlights different tabs. When I'm just on the desktop and do that button combination it highlights different icons on my taskbar. I used a keyboard tester and I found out when I press those letters it thinks I'm pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, but other then that I don't know how to turn it off or disable it.

Comment: If you have confirmed it is hardware issue with keyboard test software, then the only way is to change the keyboard to another model, which is wired differently.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hardware issue - the way how your keyboard is wired internally.
You could try to confirm that with some keyboard testing program, like eg. Passmark KeyboardTest. It should show what your computer see, when you press certain keys or combinations on your keyboard.

If that is not the case, there might be some sophisticated key combination detection built into Chrome and that would need a bit further investigation.